# Auto refresh page every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JSP page which has to display the status of various jobs that are running. Some of these jobs take time, so it takes a while for their status to change from processing to complete.

Is it a good idea to have a javascript function that would refresh the page every 30 seconds or so? Are there any ramifications for having a script that is constantly refreshing a page?

The other option is to have a refresh button which on click would refresh the page.

Comment: Don't refresh the whole page, refresh only the content-a part of the page that needs to be updated using _AJAX_

Comment: @Tushar has a good suggestion...just refresh the parts of the page where content needs updating. A refresh script might be as simple as a jQuery `.load()` rigged to fire every 30 seconds inside a requestAnimationFrame loop.

Comment: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/02/06/a-beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-in-your-website/

Comment: how do you call every 30 seconds with a "requestAnimationFrame loop"?

Comment: @dandavis. Use the automatic timestamp argument sent into rAF's loop function and .load() whenever the timestamp has elapsed another 30 seconds.

Comment: i think `setTimeout` is what you're after, rAF is for animation...

Comment: @dandavis, rAF is simply a timing loop that is both well coordinated with the display refresh cycle and also receives a very useful high precision timestamp as an argument. It also suspends looping if the browser tab loses focus. And it helps prevent stacking of code that wasn't able to complete when the last loop ended. It's a great general purpose timing loop -- not just for animation. BTW, instead of `setTimeout` you might want to recommend `setInterval` ;-)

Comment: @markE: setInterval would do the same thing as setTimeout if the page was refreshed from the callback...

Answer (score 245, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this. If you want the page to be refreshed you actually don't need JavaScript, the browser can do it for you if you add this `meta` tag in your `head` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

The browser will then refresh the page every 30 seconds.

If you really want to do it with JavaScript, then you can refresh the page every 30 seconds with `Location.reload()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)) inside a `setTimeout()`:

```
window.setTimeout( function() {
  window.location.reload();
}, 30000);
```

If you don't need to refresh the whole page but only a part of it, I guess an AJAX call would be the most efficient way.

Comment: doesn't setTimeout runs only once, setInterval fires repeatedly?

Comment: Yes but since the page completely reloads, `setTimeout` will be executed again

Comment: Also helpful, do not reload if page is not visible in browser to safe resources: `if (!document.hidden) { ... }` - Together with `$(window).on('focus', function() { window.location.reload(); });`

Answer (score 34):

Just a simple line of code in the head section can refresh the page

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">`

although its not a javascript function, its the simplest way to accomplish the above task hopefully.

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted, it answers the question. Probably not the best way to do it but that is up to the OP to decide.

Comment: Probably a legacy downvote from when it did not answer the question.

Comment: The jsp iterates over a collection and populates a table with the fields of the collection. One of the fields of the collection is the status field. This is the field I am interested in updating. However, I think it isn't a simple javascript function, as I will probably have to call the DAO to recreate the collection so that I have the updated status field value.

Answer (score 13):

If you want refresh the page you could use like this, but refreshing the page is usually not the best method, it better to try just update the content that you need to be updated.

**javascript:**

```
<script language="javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 30000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Though in this case either will be fine but `setTimeout` inherently triggers only once `setInterval` continues indefinitely.

```
<script language="javascript">
setInterval(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 30000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why does it matter in this case? The page reloads, and the script will run indefinitely.