# How can i refresh my page in tapestry after some interval

Tags: tapestry, tml

I want to auto-refresh my web page within every 30 seconds and there is one condition if that condition is true I don't want to refresh it. How I should configure it?

Comment: what is the condition? can it be evaluated on the client-side in the browser or it needs to execute server-side logic? if client-side is enough this may be done in JS https://stackoverflow.com/q/32913226/2414933

Comment: Below is my code.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved like this

```
<t:if test="someCondition"> 
    <span t:type="Zone" t:id="someStatusTaskZone" t:update="show" t:mixins="poll" t:interval="300">                          
        <script> 
            (function() {
                 location.reload(); 
            })(); 
       </script>        
   </span>        
</t:if>
```