# Is it possible to make my site refresh every 15 seconds or so using JS?

Tags: javascript

I dont know much about programming but, I need my site to periodically refresh.
Does anyone know a way that I could make this happen by using JavaScript? Ive reviewed questions such as [Auto refresh page every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913226/auto-refresh-page-every-30-seconds) but its not very useful because I need more than that for the code to run.So ff you respond to this with code, could you include the whole piece of code, not just the snippet

Comment: "I need more than that for the code to run"  — (looks at accepted answer on that question). No, you don't.

Comment: The first answer on that page is pretty complete, for the `<meta>` tag you literally just paste that line between the `<head>` tags. For the `window....` code you put that between `<script>` tags in the `<body>` of your html.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your meta tags at the beginning of your page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

or Javascript at the bottom of your page

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

Remember to include `<script> Code here </script>`