# How to periodically refresh Python Flask webpage?

Tags: python, flask

How do I periodically refresh my Python Flask webpage? All the current questions online seem to be focused on auto-refreshing the page when there is some change in the code, but this is not what I'm trying to do. I want the Chrome tab to periodically refresh, say, every minute.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header

Comment: or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913226/auto-refresh-page-every-30-seconds might be better.